# zsh colored prompt

Tags: zsh, colors

this is my PROMPT

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[green]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[white]%}%m%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg[yellow]%}%~%{$reset_color%} $(git_super_status)
%{$fg[white]%}\$%{$reset_color%}'
```

Yes, the new line is intentional, it looks like this:

```
carlo@machine:~ 
$
```

My problem is that the white portion is not white, but it stays gray. I've tried this with xterm and urxvt.

`XTERM` variable is set to `xterm-256color` for `xterm`, 
and to `rxvt-unicode-256color` for `urxvt`.
If I use terminator, with `TERM` set to `xterm`, the white color is correctly visualized. I've also tried setting `TERM=xterm` also in the other terminals, but it did not help.
Do anyone have an idea of what is happening here?

**EDIT**
I've forgot to tell that using `urxvt`/`xterm` and `bash`, the white color is perfectly visualized.
Also I've played a little with escape codes, I can set the variable to white italic, white blinking, white bold but now just plain white.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, you should rather set `TERM` variable, not `XTERM`.

Comment: Sorry, a typo, edited the answer.

Comment: How about setting white color explicitly: `PS1=$'%{\e[37m%}XYZ> %{\e[0m%}'`?

Comment: OK, so try high intensity: `PS1=$'%{\e[97m%}XYZ> %{\e[0m%}'`. Also run `echotc Co` in problematic terminal and report the output.

Answer (score 3):

you may want the bold white color:

```
PS1='%F{green}%n%f@%B%F{white}%m%f%b:%F{yellow}%~ $(stuff)%B%F{white}\$%f%b '
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that, and it works in fact, but that is not exactly what I want. If I do not find an alternative I will use that eventually.